# Which is more efficient in python (and in general): iterate over short list and searching in the longer one, or vice versa?

Tags: python, list, performance, set

I have two lists, both contain integers represented as strings. `large_list` is large, up to low 10s of thousands of elements. `small_list` is smaller, up to hundreds of elements. I am filtering the larger one by the smaller one. I'm curious to know which is more efficient:

(a)

```
for element in small_list:
    if element in large_list:
        (do something)
```

(b)

```
for element in large_list:
    if element in small_list:
        (do something)
```

for option (a), the iteration count is limited by the length of `small_list`, but for each one, a search has to be executed on the full `large_list`.
for option (b), the iteration goes through the entire `large_list` but each search is executed on `small_list`.

I understand that sets are hashed, so the best option here ought to be to take `large_set = set(large_list)`, iterate through `small_list`, and do each search on `large_set`. But if we take sets out of the equation, is option (a) more efficient, or is option (b)?

Answer (score 5):

You can speculate, you can calculate

```py
import timeit

small_list = list(range(10,20))
large_list = list(range(15,115))

def small_in_large():
    c = 0
    for element in small_list:
        if element in large_list:
            c += 1
    return c

def large_in_small():
    c = 0
    for element in large_list:
        if element in small_list:
            c += 1
    return c

t1 = timeit.timeit(small_in_large, globals=globals(), number=10000)
t2 = timeit.timeit(large_in_small, globals=globals(), number=10000)
print("small_in_large() {:.3f} seconds".format(t1))
print("large_in_small() {:.3f} seconds".format(t2))
```

On my machine:

```
small_in_large() 0.164 seconds
large_in_small() 0.730 seconds
```

Comment: good find, apparently `x in y` is heavily optimized C code, and it's more beneficial to apply it to the larger list.

Comment: Yeah. Especially in Python where getting into the optimized C code makes a big difference, algorithmic complexity analysis is only part of the story.

Answer (score 3):

(a) would be much more efficient because its only ever checking until a match is found.

```
large_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
small_list = ['4', '6', '10']

for n in small_list:
    if n in large_list:
        print(f"Found {n} in large_list. Do something.")
    else:
        print(f"{n} not found in large_list.")
```

Output:

```
Found 4 in large_list. Do something.
Found 6 in large_list. Do something.
Found 10 in large_list. Do something.
```

(b) is much slower because it depends on the length of both lists because it will check every single element against each other in both lists.

```
large_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
small_list = ['4', '6', '10']

for n in large_list:
    if n in small_list:
        print(f"Found {n} in small_list. Do something.")
    else:
        print(f"{n} not found in small_list.")
```

Output:

```
1 not found in small_list.
2 not found in small_list.
3 not found in small_list.
Found 4 in small_list. Do something.
5 not found in small_list.
Found 6 in small_list. Do something.
7 not found in small_list.
8 not found in small_list.
9 not found in small_list.
Found 10 in small_list. Do something.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's O(m*n) in both approaches, where m and n are the lengths of the two lists - searching a list for presence of an element is O(n) on the length of the list, because in the worst case you have to inspect every element. And for complexity analysis you need to consider the worst case. So you have to do m different O(n) operations, or n different O(m) operations, giving the same product. I do agree that in practice it's likely to be faster to iterate over the smaller list, because you'll get more benefit when early termination _is_ possible. But profiling would be the best way to check.

Comment: Yea, you're right. Oversight. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper @CDubyuh thanks both for taking the time, this makes a ton of sense. I hadn't thought through the worst-case vs potential for early termination, that made it click. In practice, I'm doing as advised as well as converting `large_list` to a set.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be this guy, but current answers are flawed:

- I think @CDubyuh got explanation a bit wrong. In both cases checking "is in list" is stopped when match is found.
- @mugiseyebrows is not making fair test because you need to shuffle the list first, and make several repetitions using different lists.

#### Probability of finding element of one list in another

It is (generally, not in every case) more likely to find element from small list in a large list and stop checking "in the middle" than it is to find element from large list in a small list. Lets take example from mugiseyebrows, where 50% of small list values are in the large list. Will also fix it a bit by adding random shuffling and test repetitions.

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np

t1_stats = []
t2_stats = []
for n_rep in range(100):
    small_list = list(range(5,15))  # small list and large list have common subset of values
    large_list = list(range(10,115))
    random.shuffle(small_list)
    random.shuffle(large_list)

    def small_in_large():
        c = 0
        for element in small_list:
            if element in large_list:
                c += 1
        return c

    def large_in_small():
        c = 0
        for element in large_list:
            if element in small_list:
                c += 1
        return c

    t1_stats.append(timeit.timeit(small_in_large, globals=globals(), number=10000))
    t2_stats.append(timeit.timeit(large_in_small, globals=globals(), number=10000))
print("small_in_large() {:.5f} seconds".format(np.mean(t1_stats)))
print("large_in_small() {:.5f} seconds".format(np.mean(t2_stats)))
```

```
small_in_large() 0.06509 seconds
large_in_small() 0.09971 seconds
```

If we make small list subset of large, the differences are bigger, as expected:

```
    small_list = list(range(10,20))  # small list is subset of the large list
    large_list = list(range(10,115))
```

```
small_in_large() 0.04701 seconds
large_in_small() 0.09866 seconds
```

#### number of calls to in operateor

Also, there are more calls to `in` operator in the second case which will have its effect on performance too. To test how it affects the performance, let's create test when small and large lists have no common values.

```
    small_list = list(range(0,10))  # small list and large list are completely different
    large_list = list(range(15,115))
```

```
small_in_large() 0.07443 seconds
large_in_small() 0.08789 seconds
```

As you can see difference between both cases is much smaller. Still small_in_large is ~15% faster

#### Summary

- Small_in_large is always faster.
- The bigger is joint subset of values between the lists, the more performant small_in_large will be.

Answer (score 1):

Internal C code (e.g. the `in` comparison operator) is always going to be faster than iterating using python code.  In this case the outer for-loop (python code) is your bottleneck so, even without measuring it, using the smaller list in the for-loop is going to be more efficient.

There are various ways to get better performance using more of the built-in functions (C code) in your main loop:

```
# using filter:

for c in filter(small_list.__contains__,large_list):
    (do something)

# using a set: (does not preserve order)

for c in set(small_list).intersection(large_list):
    (do something)

# using both:

for c in filter(set(small_list).__contains__,large_list):
    (do something)

# using a dictionary: (preserves order)

for c in filter(dict.fromkeys(small_list).__contains__,large_list):
    (do something)

# more options are possible if one or both of the lists are sorted
```

Keep in mind that, if your lists contain duplicates, these and even your original variants may not give the same result

If you abstract out the difference between C-code and Python code (as would be the case in the 1st filter example above) and exclude specific internal optimizations, in theory there would not by any difference.  Assuming a regular distribution, finding an item in the large list would take L/2 iterations on average (L being its length) and finding an item in the small one would take S/2 iterations.   Multiplying by the outer loop's iteration count gives either S*(L/2) or L*(S/2).  Because multiplication is commutative, both give the same number of iterations (S*L/2).
Actual data and internal code are rarely that regular/symmetrical so, depending on what you are working with, you will need to make choices that fit the context and/or apply to the majority of use cases.